# Обсуждение схемы для взаимодействия с базой данных.

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Здравствуйте, уважаемые профессионалы.
Выношу вопрос для обсуждения. Вопрос касается взаимодействия программы с базой данных.

Ну так вот. Есть множество приемов для работы с БД. Как вы думаете, хорош ли прием работы, описанный ниже. Если нет, то прокомментируйте, что там плохо.

Допустим, создан некий интерфейс работы с БД, полностью берущий на себя ответственность создания и удаления подключений и предоставляющий информацию из базы в разных видах таким образом (назовем его `DBProvider`):

1. Создать новый объект `DBProvider`;
2. Вызвать функцию получения готовых данных;

Допустим, что у нас созданы сущности (`@Entity`) для каждой таблицы. Конечно, для реализации многих задач, одними объектами сущностей не обойтись. Необходимо создавать свои собственные, состоящие из смеси нескольких сущностей, и данные в них надо помещать с учетом некоторых условий запроса. Например, есть две таблицы: сотрудники и начальники. У каждого сотрудника и начальника есть свои стандартные данные, и еще к сотруднику прикреплен свой начальник (надеюсь, зависимость уже видна). Нам понадобилось создать объект `Подчиненные` (т.е. подчиненные некоего начальника, и данные, допустим, только ФИО). Объект примерно будет такой:

```
class Subordinates {
    privat String chiefName;
    privat String[] subordinateNames;
    //Геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

Конечно, инициализировать его придется в классе, который его использует (или в другом месте) путем запроса к БД, преобразованию, занесению данных в поля объекта ...
Ну а если сделать так, чтобы этот класс сам себе доставал данные из базы по параметрам, которых ему передавать в конструктор или отдельно. Например:

```
class Subordinates {
    privat String chiefName;
    privat String[] subordinateNames;

    public Subordinates(int chiefId, int minRate, int maxRate) {
        DBProvider dbp = new DBProvider();
        //извлечение из бд записей и
        //инициализация полей в соответствии с критериями поиска
    }
    //Геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

Тут уже выходит, что объект этого класса полностью сам за себя в ответе. И создание подобных объектов уже сведется только к тому, чтобы передавать туда критерии поиска. Мало того, уже нет необходимости создавать некий слой в программе, где будут извлекаться данные (например как в паттерне DAO).
Если выразиться графически, то будет примерно следующее:

[image]

Тут `ValueObject` использует `DBProvider` для извлечения данных, затем делает все необходимые вычисления и преобразования с полученными данными. В итоге получается готовый объект с данными (`Value Object`), которым уже и пользуется объект бизнес-логики. Не забываем, что `DBProvider` полностью инкапсулирует все операции работы с БД.

Если кто-то видел статью, подтверждающую или опровергающую удобство этой схемы, то прошу ссылку. Если кто не согласен или согласен с этой схемой, прошу написать свое мнение, плюс доводы. С радостью приму предложение схемы, которая намного лучше этой.

*UPD1*:
Более подробно опишу принцип действия. В методы `DBProvider` надо отправлять `SQL`-запросы на добавление, удаление или редактирование данных. Т.е. в моем примере конструктор класса `Subordinates` будет отправлять запрос, например

```
//...
chiefName = dbp.getString("Select имя from начальники where код=" + chiefId);
subordinateNames = dbp.getObjects(/* Запрос на выборку данных одного столбца */).toArray();
//...
```

Ну вот примерный принцип работы. Также пусть `DBProvider` может также инициализировать простые объекты (бины или сущности) и возвращать массив этих объектов уже с данными. Ну и задачи по обновлению данных в базе после того как были изменены данные в объекте `Subordinates`, лежит на нем самом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну для начала профессионалов здесь не так уж много - в основном начинающие.
По поводу вашей схемы - такая схема много где встречается и многими используется. Особенно ораклистами. Недостатки у нее примерно такие:

- потеря некоторой гибкости при извлечении данных - "сложные" фильтры труднее применить
- при изменении структуры данных не забывать изменять и классы
- если извлечение данных сопровождается созданием новых подключении или частым переподключением к базе данных - то надо учитывать что данный ресурс может оказаться не бесконечным - в какой-то момент могут начаться тормоза.

Если эти моменты вас не смущают, то можете пользоваться такой схемой без проблем. Плюсы такого подхода думаю вы и сами знаете.

Answer (score 1):

Сразу возникает вопрос - как Вы в этой схеме собираетесь реализовать запросы данных более сложные, чем простая выборка всей таблицы. Забрать всю работу у сервера? задание критериев фильтрации далеко не исчерпывает задачи более-менее сложной БД

Comment: Обновил свой вопрос. Ну и еще добавлю, что отправка всех видов запросов идет от объекта, использующего `DBProvider` в качестве параметра для функции.  
  
Да, и по поводу того, что забирать всю работу у сервера баз данных: существуют опробованные и признанные такие методики, когда БД является только хранилищем. И никакого там программирования функций и триггеров; даже автоинкременты не ставят.

Comment: Вы представляете себе реляционную базу данных, как несколько таблиц, записи которых связаны между собой - умозрительно или физически. Мне такой взгляд представляется несколько... э-э-э ограниченным (слово можно подобрать другое). Реляционная алгебра - это система операций, операндами которых являются таблицы и результатом - таблицы (отношения). Вы же редуцировали реляционную базу к сетевой

Comment: Мда. Я определенно еще не разбираюсь хорошо во всем этом. Поэтому мне важно мнение более опытных. И также важно знать и ваше мнение по этому поводу. Если есть что ответить и поправить меня, то будьте так добры

Comment: Да нет. Я думаю, это вполне работоспособно. Для большинства простых задач

Answer (score 1):

Я, может быть, не до конца понял Вашу мысль. Во-первых, "слой", о котором Вы упомянули, все-таки отвечает за оба направления передачи данных: и в БД, и из БД. Ваша схема предназначена только для получения данных из БД.

Во-вторых,для того, чтобы создать экземпляр класса, Вам необходимо знать (помнить наизусть) какие-то величины БД, в Вашем примере - это Начальник. Или же список начальников к моменту создания экземпляра должен лежать перед Вами. Поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если я ошибаюсь.